# Python get number from group of numbers

Tags: python, numbers

I want to find out with how many times I can build a number from a group of numbers:

```
possible_numbers = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16
```

If I want number 23 I need

```
1x 16
0x 8
1x 4
1x 2
1x 1
```

Is there any built in function in Python to do this?

Edit: The numbers are fixed to 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128. Multiple selections are possible.

Since there is no build in function, I'll code it myself.

Comment: Is `23x 1` also a valid output?

Comment: @Junuxx: this isn't really about factorization, it's about finding an integer partition with a restricted summand set.

Comment: I think this is actually a coin change problem, regardless of whether the original poster was thinking in those terms.

Comment: No, the numbers are limited to 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128
@DSM exactly, that's it
I have to read about coin change

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that the possible numbers are always powers of two, you basically want to convert the number to binary format. This is easy with the built-in [bin function](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#bin):

```
>>> mylist = [int(x) for x in bin(23)[2:]]
>>> print mylist
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

To get the output exactly like you showed in your question:

```
>>> for i, j in enumerate(mylist):
...     print '%ix %i' % (j, 2**(len(mylist)-i-1))
...
1x 16
0x 8
1x 4
1x 2
1x 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your numbers are not limited to powers of two, this solution should work.  It is definitely not polished or efficient, but it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def factors(desired, numbers):
    if desired == 0:
        return []
    elif desired < 0:
        return None

    for number in sorted(numbers, reverse=True):
        f = factors(desired - number, numbers)
        if f is not None:
            f.append(number)
            return f


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(sys.argv[1])
    possibles = map(int, sys.argv[2].split())
    f = factors(n, possibles)
    print f

    for i in sorted(possibles, reverse=True):
        print "{0}x {1}".format(f.count(i), i)
```

Here are some examples:

```
$ python test.py 23 "1 2 4 8 16"
[1, 2, 4, 16]
1x 16
0x 8
1x 4
1x 2
1x 1

$ python test.py 23 "1 2 5 8 16"
[2, 5, 16]
1x 16
0x 8
1x 5
1x 2
0x 1

$ python test.py 23 "1 2 3 8 16"
[1, 3, 3, 16]
1x 16
0x 8
2x 3
0x 2
1x 1

$ python test.py 23 "1 2 3 8 17"
[3, 3, 17]
1x 17
0x 8
2x 3
0x 2
0x 1
```

Comment: Nice generalization, +1. Instead of `reversed(sorted(possibles))`,  maybe use `sorted(possibles, reverse=True)` to get a descending list independent of the order of the input.

Comment: @Junuxx I made that change.  Thanks.

Comment: @shiva yes, and I added your example to my answer

Answer (score 2):

If repetition is not allowed, there's a neat way using powersets (and a nice powerset function cribbed from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#Python ):

```
def list_powerset(lst):
    return reduce(lambda result, x: result + [subset + [x] for subset in result], lst, [[]])

def powerset(s):
    return frozenset(map(frozenset, list_powerset(list(s))))

def valid_combos(num, lst):
    return filter(lambda x: sum(x) == num, powerset(lst))
```

This only works if the numbers only show up once, but I still think it's a fun solution. :)